# Angular JSON Response

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing

Below is a json response from my API. I would like to utilize ng-repeat in my html in order to show this data back to an end-user. How do I go about in my controller de-serializing this json data.

```
    {
  "message": "Query to return servers",
  "result": [
    {
      "meta": [
        "Computer",
        "SQLPort",
        "Domain"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "MyCompterName",
          "1433",
          "XXXX"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

here is the code for the app.js that get loaded into the index.html

```
var app = angular.module('DSCApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource','ui.router']);
```

### Config

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/DSC', {
            templateUrl: "DSC.html",
            controller: 'DscController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

### Data Factory

```
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    var urlBase = '/api';
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.getServers = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase);
     };

     return dataFactory;
}]);
```

### Controller

```
 app.controller('DscController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory',
 function  ($scope, dataFactory) {  
  $scope.status
  $scope.servers;  

  getServers();

        function getServers() {
        dataFactory.getServers()
            .success(function (srv) {
                $scope.servers = srv;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load server data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }   

}]);
```

Comment: What data do you want to parse? Have you tried searching for libraries that do the work?

Comment: I want to parse the "rows" data and essentially present it back in a formatted HTML table.

Comment: *"parse"* is an extremely vague term without context. A front end database is not very clear either and sounds rather abstract. Please read [ask]

Comment: I mis-type the word "database", my bad. So here is the general idea. My API is return the data you see above in that exact format. I am trying to build an angular module to "parse" .... de-serialize the json response so I can perform an ng-repeat. However all the example I have found, the json data does not look like what I have presented. Just need some help to figure out how to use ng-repeat to display that data back....thanks

Comment: Update the question itself with all relevant details where they can vbe easily read by all. As it stands right now the question itself is far too broad

Comment: Thank you for the info...I did just that and hopefully that will make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ng-repeat in both the table head and table body should work.

```
<html ng-app='app' ng-controller='DscController'>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <table ng-if="servers" class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th ng-repeat="head in servers.result[0].meta">{{head}}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody ng-repeat="r in servers.result">
                <tr ng-repeat="row in r.rows">
                  <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{item}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <p ng-if="!servers">{{status}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I've included the necessary repeats to handle the data exactly as it was presented.  I assume the meta will be the same for all results.

Comment: so here is my app.js that i load into the index.html

Comment: the whole front-end "thing" is new to me...I am an infrastructure developer/DBA...so rendering data back to a client is something I on the whole do not really deal with...this is my first attempt at this

Comment: Ok...gave it a try...not rendering as I expected...posted the code for the controller...I know it is something I am doing...thanks again for the help

Comment: I updated the code to use your controller name and scope variables.  Also added a ng-if to the table and ng-if to a <p> to show the status message.

Comment: here is a link to a codepen that I created to demonstrate how to implement http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/bpRvdZ

Comment: Michael..thank you so much...I am going to play with the code now..awesome work

Comment: Michael..so my factory and controller are in separate files as well as the app.js. Using your code...I am able to load and view the data...so thank you.I have three files [app.js;DscController.js;datafactory.js]. How do I get all three to play nicely and still display the data that is coming from the api call?

Comment: I would need to see the index.html. You should be loading all 3 files in there.  You mention you were loading app.js not sure about the other 2 files.  Also, you are inject 'ui.router' module but you aren't using it. You look to be using the ng-router so I wouldn't include both, as it might cause some confusion.  Are you getting an error when you attempt to load the app with your files being used? If so provide the error and I might be able to help.